# Choropleth map in Python

Tags: python, geopandas, choropleth

Below you can see one example with the Choropleth map for Italy. Below you can see an example :

```
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd

regions = ['Trentino Alto Adige', "Valle d'Aosta", 'Veneto', 'Lombardia', 'Emilia-Romagna', 'Toscana', 'Friuli-Venezia Giulia', 'Liguria', 'Piemonte', 'Marche', 'Lazio', 'Umbria', 'Abruzzo', 'Sardegna', 'Puglia', 'Molise', 'Basilicata', 'Calabria', 'Sicilia', 'Campania']
df = pd.DataFrame([regions,[10+(i/2) for i in range(20)]]).transpose()
df.columns = ['region','quantity']


#Download a geojson of the region geometries
gdf = gpd.read_file(filename=r'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/openpolis/geojson-italy/master/geojson/limits_IT_municipalities.geojson')
gdf = gdf.dissolve(by='reg_name') #The geojson is to detailed, dissolve boundaries by reg_name attribute
gdf = gdf.reset_index()

#gdf.reg_name[~gdf.reg_name.isin(regions)] Two regions are missing in your df
#16    Trentino-Alto Adige/Südtirol
#18    Valle d'Aosta/Vallée d'Aoste

gdf = pd.merge(left=gdf, right=df, how='left', left_on='reg_name', right_on='region')

ax = gdf.plot(
    column="quantity",
    legend=True,
    figsize=(15, 10),
    cmap='OrRd',
    missing_kwds={'color': 'lightgrey'});

ax.set_axis_off();
```

Output from this plot you can see below

[image]

Now I want to make same Choropleth map but now for Aremnia.You can see data below

```
data_arm = {
         'region': ['Aragatsotn','Ararat','Armavir','Gegharkunik','Kotayk','Lori','Shirak','Syunik','Tavush','Vayots Dzor','Yerevan'],
         'quantity':[0.2560,0.083,0.0120,0.9560,0.423,0.420,0.2560,0.043,0.0820,0.4560,0.019]
        }

df = pd.DataFrame(data_arm, columns = ['region',
                                   'quantity'                                   
                                   ])
df
```

So can anybody help me how to implement this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to download the `.geojson` or `.json` file for Armenia. Here is the [link download .gson](https://data.humdata.org/dataset/wfp-geonode-ica-armenia-ica-categories-areas)

[image]

It leads you to this page and click "save":

[image]

Then you can use code below :

```
data_arm = {
         'region': ['Aragatsotn','Ararat','Armavir','Gegharkunik','Kotayk','Lori','Shirak','Syunik','Tavush','Vayots Dzor','Yerevan'],
         'quantity':[0.2560,0.083,0.0120,0.9560,0.423,0.420,0.2560,0.043,0.0820,0.4560,0.019]
        }

df_arm = pd.DataFrame(data_arm, columns = ['region',
                                   'quantity'                                   
                                   ])


gdf_arm = gpd.read_file(filename=r"D:/features.json")

gdf_arm = gdf_arm.dissolve(by='adm1_name')

gdf_arm = gdf_arm.reset_index()

gdf_arm = pd.merge(left=gdf_arm, right=df_arm, how='left', left_on='adm1_name', right_on='region')

ax = gdf_arm.plot(
    column="quantity",
    legend=True,
    figsize=(15, 10),
    cmap='OrRd',
    missing_kwds={'color': 'lightgrey'});

ax.set_axis_off()
```

You will get the figure:
[image]